# Realm Code-1 Error

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to load a pre-populated realm database:

The database is looking like this:
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnQ7E.png)

I drag the file to the Xcode manage like so:
[Message Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpUIz.png)

Then my project tree looks like this: [Project Tree Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RqhR.png)

In Swift, the following code in AppDelegate for the migration

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL

    let oldPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "person", withExtension: "realm")

    if let bundlePath = oldPath {
        do {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: defaultPath!)
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: bundlePath, to: defaultPath!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 2,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

            if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Book1.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) in
                    let answer = oldObject!["answer"] as! String?
                    let name = oldObject!["name"] as! String?

                    newObject?["answer"] = answer
                    newObject?["name"] = name


                })

            }
    }, deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false, objectTypes: [Book1.self])

    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

This is the class Book1:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Book1: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var answer: String? = nil

}
```

This is the code in the ViewController which has the table:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

let cellID = "cell"

var realm: Realm!

var output : Results<Book1> {
    return realm.objects(Book1.self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    realm = try! Realm()

}

}

// MARK: Table

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return output.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = output[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}
}
```

When I run the App, I get the following error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Property 'Book1.name' does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Property 'Book1.name' does not exist, Error Code=1}

Any idea why? I checked the default database which the app has copied, and it is the right database.

Comment: Do you receive the error in your migration block? Btw your migration block makes no sense, you're copying the values from your old object with the exact same variable names, so there's no migration needed...

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have not received an error in the migration block. I tried to remove the migration block, Xcode raised an exception that a migration is needed.

Comment: Then which line of code raises that error?

Comment: viewDidLoad in the viewController (realm = try! Realm())